# Page number font doesn't change on ToC, LoF and LoT pages

Tags: page-numbering, tocloft

I would like to have the page numbers in \sffamily. On the ToC, LoF and LoT pages, the page numbers don't change to \sffamily. They only change when I delete the tocloft package. Does someone know how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in, footskip=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{center}
    \subsubsection*{Abstract}
\end{center}

\newpage

\tableofcontents 

\newpage

\listoffigures

\newpage

\listoftables   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a KOMA-class? They look exactly like you want to by default.

Comment: pakage `ngerman`  is deprecated for a while.

Comment: What package would you recommend?

Comment: The KOMA equivalent would be `scrartcl`, but since i think you are writing a sientific report, `scrreprt` or even `scrbook` might be better suited (they have chapters).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the language package, because you wrote ngerman is deprecated.

Comment: `\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}` and later `\usepackage{babel}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the instruction

```
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
```

(As you've discovered, the default page style `tocloft` applies to the ToC, LoT, and LoF is `plain`. )